# How to display dotted walkway on google maps

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3

Is there any way to show a dotted route on my website by using *google maps + javascript*.

I way able to paint simple route by using *google directions api and DirectionsRenderer* and it looks like this:

[image: simple line]

But I want this one:

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This was a hard one, but managed to figure it out..

It's not exactly the same, but you could tweak it a bit yourself. You can also make a custom "shape", you can do this by creating a custom path. [Reference](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/symbols)

The way i did it was by using a polyLine with a custom icon, code:

```
var lineSymbol = {
    path: google.maps.SymbolPath.CIRCLE,
    fillOpacity: 1,
    scale: 3
};

polylineOptionsActual = new gm.Polyline({
    strokeColor: '#9f98FF',
    strokeOpacity: 0,
    icons: [{
        icon: lineSymbol,
        offset: '0',
        repeat: '10px'
    }],
}),
```

**[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/maarten1012/yhqeqkns/)**

Answer (score 0):

According to docs page here, and I think that is something like mode of direction..

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/directions/

you could try to add mode parameter,, like this:

&mode=walking ..

and see if that makes it dotted?